# KVM hypervisor remote connections

Tags: linux-kernel, virtualization, remote-access, kvm, hypervisor

I am a newbie in the area of Linux KVM virtualization. Can anybody help how to connect to my KVM hypervisor from a remote Linux machine without using LibVirt or any other third party library.  I have searched for this but all the results that i got was using libvirt or commands related to it. I am not allowed to use any third party library and need to take the backup of my KVM from remote machine.

Can you also tell me why a deamon is required in KVM when it is not required in VMware ESXI?

Comment: Are there any KVM API's present for taking the backup of VM's running on KVM from a remote machine (without using libvirt)? This backup need to be take at different levels such as VM level, Disk level and file level.

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/440176/kvm-hypervisor-remote-access-without-libvirt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to connect, there is no need of libvirt or anything else.
You could just use vnc viewer like this: vncviewer IP:PORT

```
$ vncviewer 192.168.1.123:0 #if you using display number
$ vncviewer 192.168.1.123::5900 #if u using port number
```

i didn't quite get what you are meaning with "take the backup of my KVM" ?

Of course a daemon is required by VMware ESXI to run. Use can use ps to verify that.

Comment: i want to take teh backup of all teh VM's running on my KVM server. but I am not allowed to use any outside library or deamon. it has to be agentless. but what ever i am searching it is giving results by using libvirt or any other outside lirary. I am not getting the original KVM commands for this.


and regarding VMware ESXI, libvirt home site says that we do not require any deamon for that.http://libvirt.org/drvesx.html

Comment: this backup need to be taken from remote machine, without creating any temprary file.

Answer (score 0):

use kvm command with option `-vnc 0.0.0.0:0` and connect with command shown by Evaggelos Balaskas